Why is ResolvableType#resolveType a package-private method? What does 'single level' mean in the comment?
I'm currently working on a custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. This involves dealing with generics, so I referred to the org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder#createObjectReader method to determine the actual type used for resolution.
However, this method uses org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver#resolveType(java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.Class<?>) to obtain the specific type, but this method will loses the actual type information (return a Class).

For example, Map<String, Map<String, Object>> would be resolved to Map<Object, Object>.

What I want is a type (Type) that contains complete generic information. The most suitable method I have found so far is to use ResolvableType#resolveType.
However, this method is package-private, and I am a bit confused by the comment on this method. I am not sure if using this would cause other issues.

In addition, if I should not use this method, is there a better alternative?

